# "Request Desktop Site" button on iOS9 does not work on chat

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, mobile-web, ios

One of iOS9's best little new features is that if I long-press the "refresh" button in Mobile Safari, I am offered the option to switch to the desktop version of the site I am viewing. This works perfectly on main SE sites, but is totally non-functional on Chat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chat offers this functionality built-in (via "mobile" or "full site" links/buttons), and you've probably used it before. That is, at some point you clicked "full site" on your iPhone or whatever you're using, and got the desktop version. Then you clicked "mobile" again and got the mobile version back.

Therefore, your browser has stored (in a cookie) your explict preference to see the mobile version. This explicit preference takes precedence over the browser's user agent string – and spoofing this user agent is all that mobile browsers do to pretend you're on a desktop computer.

This behavior is arguably correct: if you have stated a preference, we should respect it – the whole point of it is to override the user agent sniffing.

That said, in order to support *both* use cases, I've made the following change: If you set an explicit preference, and this preference matches what we would have sent you anyway (*hadn't* you expressed that preference), we will remove the cookie instead of remembering your choice.

For users who never spoof their user agent string, this will not cause any change in behavior. For users who do, this means that things should mostly work as expected when they discover their browser's "request desktop site" feature even if they have used the site's built-in functionality before.

Switching back and forth between both ways may work in unexpected ways, but certainly not worse than it does right now.

You in particular may have to either

- visit chat one more time *without* using "request desktop site", or
- while using the "desktop site" feature, click chat's "full site" button.

Either of these two will cause your preference to be aligned with what your browser is representing to be, and thus remove your explicit preference.

Comment: Thanks! I switch back and forth pretty frequently because mobile chat is missing a bunch of key features, but, of course, full chat is nightmarish to use on a tiny phone screen, what with all the tiny butans. Having the shortcut to speed up the switch is handy. :)